# fscanf two lines of data, perform calc, print result, fscanf next two lines, in a single loop?

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop, struct, printf

I am using this for loop to bring in data from a file of latitude and longitude coordinates, then converting the coordinates to decimal degrees, degrees to radians, then calculating the angle of separation, and returning the distance between the two cities.  I need to compare the first two lines from the file, calculate the distance, print the results, and then do the next two lines.  I have got it exactly the way I want it, but with five identical for loops, just adjusting the loop control parameters each time.  Is there a way to accomplish this with only one loop?

```
   for(i=0;i<=ndata-9;i++)
   {     
       printf("\n%-15s     %3.0f %4.1f %c     %3.0f %4.1f %c",cities[i].location,
         cities[i].latdeg,cities[i].latmin,cities[i].directone,
         cities[i].longdeg,cities[i].longmin,cities[i].directtwo);
       fprintf(surface,"\n%-15s     %3.0f %4.1f %c     %3.0f %4.1f %c",
           cities[i].location,cities[i].latdeg,cities[i].latmin,
           cities[i].directone,cities[i].longdeg,cities[i].longmin,
           cities[i].directtwo);       
       if(cities[i-1].directone=='N')
       {
           polarone=(90.0-(cities[i-1].latdeg+(cities[i-1].latmin/60.0)))*(pi/180.0);
       }
       else
       {
           polarone=(90.0+(cities[i-1].latdeg+(cities[i-1].latmin/60.0)))*(pi/180.0);
       }
       if(cities[i].directone=='N')
       {
            polartwo=(90.0-(cities[i].latdeg+(cities[i].latmin/60.0)))*(pi/180.0);
       }
       else
       {
           polartwo=(90.0+(cities[i].latdeg+(cities[i].latmin/60.0)))*(pi/180.0);
       }
       if(cities[i-1].directtwo=='W')
       {
           azimuthone=(cities[i-1].longdeg+(cities[i-1].longmin/60.0))*(pi/180.0);
       }
       else
       {
           azimuthone=(360.0-(cities[i-1].longdeg+(cities[i-1].longmin/60.0)))*(pi/180.0);
       }
       if(cities[i].directtwo=='W')
       {   
           azimuthtwo=(cities[i].longdeg+(cities[i].longmin/60.0))*(pi/180.0);
       }
       else
       {
           azimuthtwo=(360.0-(cities[i].longdeg+(cities[i].longmin/60.0)))*(pi/180.0);
       }
       angle=acos(cos(polarone)*cos(polartwo)+sin(polarone)*sin(polartwo)*cos(azimuthtwo-azimuthone));
       distance=angle*radius;
   }
   printf("\nDistance between the two cities = %6.1f miles\n",distance); 
   fprintf(surface,"\nDistance between the two cities = %6.1f miles\n", distance);
```

Comment: Yes: why don't you perform exactly those steps inside a single loop? Anytime fscanf fails (check the return value of fscanf to be 0), you exit the loop. That is, use something along the lines of `while(true) {.... break; ...}`.

Comment: And create a function to convert your input to radians; that avoids clutter in the main loop.

Comment: I was thinking of something along those same lines, but am unsure of exactly how to program it

Comment: I just reprogrammed it again with the while break statement for when my loop control variable hit where I needed to print and it worked beautifully!!  That saves a ton of code!!

Comment: while(i==1)
        {
          printf("\nDistance between the two cities = %6.1f miles\n",
           distance); 
          fprintf(surface,"\nDistance between the two cities = %6.1f"
            "miles\n",distance);
          break;      
  }

Answer (score 0):

**DIVIDE AND CONQUER!!!**

(What follows is for demonstration purposes. I assume everything is double, and cities have type struct City. Change the types if neccessary. Also, I did not debug it.)

```
const double deg_to_rad = pi/180, half_pi = pi/2, two_pi = pi*2;

inline double RadFromDeg(double degrees, double minutes) {
    return (degrees+minutes/60)*deg_to_rad;
}

// not sure if we really need inline here
inline void ObtainPolarAzimuth(double* polar, double* azimuth, struct City* city) {
    double temp = RadFromDeg(city->latdeg, city->latmin);
    if (city->directone == 'N')
        *polar = half_pi - temp;
    else
        *polar = half_pi + temp;
    // ... blablabla longdeg blablabla longmin blablabla *azimuth
}


// ... 

    ObtainPolarAzimuth(*polar1, *azimuth1, city[i-1]); 
    ObtainPolarAzimuth(*polar2, *azimuth2, city[i]);
    // ... blablabla angle blablabla cos blablabla sin
```

Also, imho it would be better to write `direct1` and `direct2` instead of `directone` and `directtwo`.